# Culebra GUI is working very slowly

Tags: androidviewclient

Hi I am using Androidviewclient culebra tester in my windows 7 os , for starting culebra I am launching from command prompt as python culebra -G , culebra GUI started but taking long time to refresh view can anyone help me for solving this issue

Condition:- 
1. I am testing for android car infotainment system which doesn’t contains wifi 
2. I am using windows 7 os

Supporting :- 
I can use adb via usb cable / Ethernet (TCP/IP)

Please anyone can help me for solving this issue

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided many details about how much time it takes or if it's slower with this particular device than others, so I assume you are referring to the general case.

Taking the screenshot and the view tree via uiautomator (I'm also assuming this is the back-end you are using) takes time. On slower devices, it may take a couple of seconds.

However, even if this is slow, it only happens because you are **generating** tests (`culebra -G`), once the python code is generated and run, it will run faster as the screenshots are not taken and passed back unless you request them explicitly.
Also, as these tests, once **generated** are intended to be run automatically and non-interactively, it doesn't really matter a lot.

If you still think is slow, [culebra.dtmilano.com](http://culebra.dtmilano.com/) provides another back-end (`uiautomatorhelper`) which is faster and can even generate Java and Kotlin code if you consider python is too slow for your case.

Comment: Thank you Mr Milano by using python culebra -G culebra application is launching when doing touch actions culebra application is crashing showing culebra is not responding , I need script in python please help me